# Complex mysql query from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

TABLE 1 - COURSE

```
course_id
name
category_id
status
```

TABLE 2 - CATEGORY

```
category_id
category_name
```

TABLE 3 - PROFESSOR

```
prof_id
prof_name
```

TABLE 4 - COURSEANDPROF 
(relation table of COURSES and PROFESSORS, every course can have multi professors)

```
id
course_id
professor_id
```

I create two selects in my page to filters courses of my school, I've no problem to setup the where clause for category:

```
if ($_POST['category']) {
    $category = "AND courses.category_id = ".$_POST['category'];
}

select courses.*,category.name from courses INNER JOIN category ON courses.category_id = category.category_id where courses.status = 1 ".$categoria
```

How can I make the where on professors if every courses can have more than one professor?

ex:

```
Course: Learn Jquery
Category: Javascript
Professors: Kevin Smith, Sara Logan
```

Table courses

```
course_id  | name         | category_id   | status
--------------------------------------------------------
1          | Learn Jquery | 1             | 1
2          | Learn Mysql  | 3             | 0
```

Table category

```
category_id  | name     
------------------------
1            | Javascript 
3            | Database
```

Table professor

```
prof_id   | name     
------------------------
12        | Kevin Smith 
33        | Mike White
34        | Sara Logan
```

Table courseandprof

```
id   | course_id  |  professor_id
-----------------------------------
12   | 1          | 12
33   | 1          | 34
34   | 2          | 33
```

I need to filter by category or/and by Professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this SQL code:

```
SELECT courses.course_id AS course_id, courses.name AS course_name, 
    category.name AS category_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT professor.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS professor_name
FROM courses 
    LEFT JOIN category ON category.category_id = courses.category_id
    LEFT JOIN courseandprof ON courseandprof.course_id = courses.course_id
    LEFT JOIN professor ON professor.prof_id = courseandprof.professor_id
WHERE courses.status = 1
GROUP BY courses.course_id;
```

Beside the WHERE clause, you can put your other filters there, eg. `professor.prof_id = 12`, or `category.category_id = 1`.

If a course has multiple professors, this query displays one row of course and concatenated professors with `", "` separator.

```
course_name: "Learn Jquery"
category_name: "Javascript"
professor_name: "Kevin Smith, Sara Logan"
```

Main table to query is `courses`. Then we left join `category`, `courseandprof` and `professor` tables. Multiple rows per course will be shown if the same course has been associated to multiple professors via `courseandprof` table. That's why we need to group it per course (using `course_id`), then we concatenate professor names in the SELECT clause.